# Store results of function in complex object (?) in R

Tags: r, function, object

everbody knows this functions:

```
    fitted_lm = lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
    > class(fitted_lm)
    [1] "lm"

    fitted_lm$
```

In my global environment I see that fitted_lm is stored as a list, but when i call the class function on the object, I get "lm" as result. These object allows it to easily access different values with the "$"-sign. How can I store my own results that kind of way?

For example something like this:

```
complex_output <- function(x) {
    row.means <- rowMeans(x)
    col.means <- colMeans(x)
    result <- list(row.means, col.means)
    return(result)
}

complex_result <- complex_output(x = mtcars)
complex_result[[1]]
complex_result$ # does not work
```

I can of course access all results via double brackets, but it would be much more convenient to access them with the "$"-sign. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning names to the elements in the list generated by your function:

```
complex_output <- function(x) {
    row.means <- rowMeans(x)
    col.means <- colMeans(x)
    result <- list(r=row.means, c=col.means)
    return(result)
}

complex_result$r
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much for the fast und great response. That´s really awesome :-)

Comment: sure! But I have to wait eight minutes to do that :-)